# How to use font-weight on custom font in js jsPDF

Tags: vue.js, fonts, nuxt.js, jspdf, html-to-pdf

I have used the jsPDF `^2.5.1` to convert html to pdf on nuxt 3 project. I have used the `Nunito` Google font on the PDf. The issue is it is not taking the font-weight property and all fonts showing the same weight.

I have tried this article [link](https://www.devlinpeck.com/content/jspdf-custom-font).
Same as mentioned here I have downloaded my fonts and set it on the PDF below

```js
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";
import { font, fontBold } from "@/public/font";

let doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [1665, 1000]);
  
doc.addFileToVFS("Nunito.ttf", font);
doc.addFont("Nunito.ttf", "Nunito", "normal");
doc.setFont("Nunito", "normal");

let pdfHtml = '<h1>Some of <span style="font-weight:600">my</span> HTML</h1>'

doc.html(pdfHtml, {
  callback: function (doc) {
    doc.save('pdf.pdf');
  },
});
```

Even though I have tried to export bold and normal both font and set it using `doc.setFont` but still it only takes the normal font.
Please help me with this and let me know if still not clear or want more details from me.

Thank you